PHP Google BetaAnalyticsDataClient get date of first page visit
I have the following code for getting a list of pages with the most page visits in the last 7 days from Google Analytics.
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Client\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\RunReportRequest;

$property_id = '12345678';
$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();
$request = (new RunReportRequest())
    ->setProperty('properties/' . $property_id)
    ->setDateRanges([
        new DateRange([
            'start_date' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-7 days')),
            'end_date' => 'today',
        ]),
    ])
    ->setDimensions([
        new Dimension([
            'name' => 'pagePath',
        ]),
    ])
    ->setMetrics([
        new Metric([
            'name' => 'activeUsers',
        ])
    ])
    ->setLimit(10);

This works fine, but I want to know if there is a way to also filter the results by first time page visits, in order to filter out pages that are older than the date range I specified. I've tried adding the following:
new Dimension([
    'name' => 'firstSessionDate',
]),

But that does not give me the results I want. I've looked here but I can't really find an answer to my problem. Any help is appreciated.

Hi, Try first_open as shown in the documentation.
